# Javascript onClick clear does not work inside php echo

Tags: php, javascript

Here is code without php echo and it works.

```
<tr id='row1'>
<td><input type="text" name="date_day[]" id="date_day1" class="row_changed1"size="1"></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript://" onClick="clearChildren(document.getElementById('row1'))">Clear</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

But I must use the same in php echo

Tried this

```
 echo "<tr id='row11'>

 <td>
 <input type='text' name='date_day[]' id='date_day1' class='row_changed1' value='" .$post_date_day. "' size='1'>
 </td>

 <td>
 <input type='text' name='entry_id[]' id='entry_id1' class='row_changed1' size='5' value='".$post_entry_id ."' >
 </td>

 <td>
 <input type='text' name='row_id[]' id='row_id1' value='" .$post_row_id ."' size='1'>
 </td>

 <td>
 <a href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"clearChildren(document.getElementById('row11'))\">Clear</a>

 </td>

 </tr>";
```

But does not clear. Possibly because of incorrect usage of `'` and `"` but can not understand what is correct way. Experimented changing `'` to `"` and vice versa, but without success.

clearChildren function

```
function clearChildren(element) {
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
var e = element.childNodes[i];
if (e.tagName) switch (e.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
case 'input':
switch (e.type) {
case "radio":
case "checkbox": e.checked = false; break;
case "button":
case "submit":
case "image": break;
default: e.value = ''; break;
}
break;
case 'textarea': e.value = ''; break;
case 'select': e.selectedIndex = -1; break;
default: clearChildren(e);
}
}
}
```

And view source (selected) is this

```
input name="date_day[]" id="date_day1" class="row_changed1" value="" size="1" type="text">

<input name="entry_id[]" id="entry_id1" class="row_changed1" size="5" value="24/1305" type="text">

<input name="row_id[]" id="row_id1" value="24" size="1" type="text">

<a href="javascript://" onclick="clearChildren(document.getElementById('row11'))">Clear</a>
```

Comment: It may be helpful to know what the clear function actually is..

Comment: can you post your php output to understand html logic

Comment: What do you see when you `View Source` of the resulting page?

Comment: Can we see `clearChildren` JS Function? Your output HTML seems to be in a valid format

Comment: @Stephen@ From my knowledge clear empty/clear all input fields. But, please advice, how it can help me to find solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<table><tr id='row11'>

 <td>
 <input type='text' name='date_day[]' id='date_day1' class='row_changed1' value='' size='1'>
 </td>

 <td>
 <input type='text' name='entry_id[]' id='entry_id1' class='row_changed1' size='5' value='' >
 </td>

 <td>
 <input type='text' name='row_id[]' id='row_id1' value='' size='1'>
 </td>

 <td>
 <a href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"clearChildren(document.getElementById('row11'));\">Clear</a>

 </td>

 </tr></table>";
```

Try this. I think this issue came up due to not proper table structure.

Comment: Thank you. Works as necessary. Ah... i see the only i needed was <table>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your html as php variable you can use following approach:

```
$post_date_day =111;
$html = <<< EOD
<tr id='row1'>
    <td>
        <input type='text' name='date_day[]' id='date_day1' class='row_changed1' value="$post_date_day" size='1'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="clearChildren(document.getElementById('row1'))">Clear</a>
    </td>
</tr>
EOD;

echo $html;
```

This will keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve your problem by wrapping the html code in a  tag. The function is properly executed and can access the DOM elements in the echo statement.

```
<?php
echo "
    <table>
        <tr id='row11'>
             <!-- put your td's here.... -->
             <td>
                  <a href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"alert(document.getElementById('row11'))\">Clear</a>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You have started your php code with ", you should write followine line as

```
 <a href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"clearChildren(document.getElementById('row11'))\">Clear</a>
```

should be:-

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='clearChildren(document.getElementById(\"row11\"))'>Clear</a>
```

Whenever possible you should use id of columns instead or row.

Comment: You mean to change my code to <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='clearChildren(document.getElementById(\"row11\"))'>Clear</a>? Does not work....

Answer (score 0):

don't know but maybe it's the value in clearChildren brackets namely in (), the `document.getElementById('row11');` returns null, when i only write 'row11' it returns it...

Sorry if it's not enough, i mainly program in php/mysql and a little bit in js/jquery...